# next.js environment variables are undefined (Next.js 10.0.5)

Tags: javascript, environment-variables, next.js, undefined

I am coding a website with Next.js and I tried to add google Tag Manager.
I followed the tutorial on the Next.js Github example but for some reasons I can't access to my environment variables. 
It says my variable is undefined. 
I created a file .env.local on my project folder (at the same level as components, node_modules, pages, etc)
In this file I created a variable like this (test purpose) :

```
NEXT_PUBLIC_DB_HOST=localhost
```

And on my index page I tried this code :

```
console.log("test ", process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_DB_HOST);
```

But in my console I get a "test  undefined". 
I tried to put my variable into an .env file instead, without success.
What I am doing wrong ?

Comment: Have your tried to reload next server?

Comment: I'm not sure to understand what you mean. I stopped what was in my vscode terminal and did a yarn dev again.
Is there anything else to do to reload the next server ?

Comment: Yep, just that. It did not help? Are you sure that `.env` file at the same level as `package.json`? Not quite sure what else can help.

Comment: Ok, I'm stupid ! I found my mistake...
I put a ":" instead of a "=".
I'm ashamed...

Comment: Thanks a lot @FlorieAnstett I did the same mistake and wasted more than 2 hours

Comment: If you're trying to do it on the Client Side, follow the Dijalma Silva contribution to Bellow

Answer (score 153):

This envs just works in Server Side. To access this envs in Client Side, you need declare in the next.config.js

This way:

```js
module.exports = {
  reactStrictMode: true,
  env: {
    BASE_URL: process.env.BASE_URL,
  }
}
```

Comment: As of Nextjs version 9.4 next.config.js is no longer suggested as the environment strategy. Are you using an older version of NextJS or do you find this to be the only way to have success?

Comment: I was just having this issue and this resolved my error while on Next 10.0.3

Comment: On Next +9, prefix the variables using `NEXT_PUBLIC_`. This will expose them on the browser.

Comment: I am on Next 12.1 and "NEXT_PUBLIC_" did not work for me even after restarting the server. This did

Answer (score 82):

1. Create **.env (all environments)**, **.env.development** (development environment), and **.env.production** (production environment).
2. Add the prefix NEXT_PUBLIC to all of your environment variables.

> NEXT_PUBLIC_API_URL=http://localhost:3000/

3. Use with prefix process.env

> process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_API_URL

4. Stop the server and restart it:

> npm run dev

5. This solution for [version 9.4.0](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/configuring/environment-variables) and above.

Comment: Note that it if you try to console log it will only log to your terminal not your browser console

Answer (score 38):

For those using NextJS +9 and looking for environment variables in the browser, you should use the `NEXT_PUBLIC_` prefix. Example:

```
NEXT_PUBLIC_ANALYTICS_ID=123456789
```

See [documentation for reference](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/environment-variables#exposing-environment-variables-to-the-browser).

Answer (score 25):

Restarting the server worked for me.

1. Edit & save .env.local
2. Stop the server and restart it, `npm run dev`
3. You should get an output on the next line like this:

```
> klout@0.1.0 dev
> next dev

Loaded env from [path]/.env.local
```

Answer (score 17):

After spending countless hours on this, I found that there is a tiny little paragraph in both the pre and post nextjs 9.4 documentation:

- (Pre-9.4) https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next.config.js/environment-variables (same as [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68189283/12070297))

  > Next.js will replace process.env.customKey with 'my-value' at **build time**.
- (^9.4) https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/environment-variables

  > In order to keep server-only secrets safe, Next.js replaces process.env.* with the correct values at **build time**.

Key words being **BUILD TIME**. This means you must have set these variables when running `next build` and not (just) at `next start` to be available for the client side to access these variables.

Comment: Ugh, this was the key for me. I had set these vars using an npm script, but it was after build time, but before starting my server.

Comment: I do get this issue. Then my question is: when in development, I have my API key which I want to keep with server side. How am I going to debug the code where it uses the API key in the server side without building the project?

Answer (score 10):

For video reference codegrepper link
https://youtu.be/6qhF9l_AgAk

process.env only work in server not in browser so it will show undefined
to fixed it use NEXT_PUBLIC_before APi key in .env.local or .env
this solution only work from version 9 of nextjs.

**NEXT_PUBLIC_BACKEND_API="http://localhost:1337/graphql"**

secret environment like MongoURl and openAi key shouldn't be put using
Next_PUBLIC_ else it will expose to browser and everyone can use it.

**MONGO_URL=**

**OPENAI_API_KEY=**

Answer (score 3):

This is my next.config.js file.

```
/** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */
const nextConfig = {
  reactStrictMode: true,
  env: {
    BASE_URL: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_SITE_URL,
  },
};

module.exports = nextConfig;
```

Restart the server and it worked fine. using Nextjs 12.1.0 with typescript

Comment: Do you use dotenv or something? Doesn't work for me. But I'm using inside monorepo, which have dotenv dependency in one of other package

Answer (score 2):

Adding with the most recent version of the [documentation](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next.config.js/runtime-configuration) on this, v12+.

Using the next.config.js file you can specify server and client variables:

```
module.exports = {
  serverRuntimeConfig: {
    // Will only be available on the server side
    mySecret: 'secret',
    secondSecret: process.env.SECOND_SECRET, // Pass through env variables
  },
  publicRuntimeConfig: {
    // Will be available on both server and client
    staticFolder: '/static',
  },
}
```

You can still use an env.local file, and pass the variable in to the next.config.js file.  For example:

```
 publicRuntimeConfig: {
   DB_URL: process.env.DB_URL
 }
```

And then you can access the variable like this:

```
import getConfig from 'next/config';
const { publicRuntimeConfig } = getConfig();
publicRuntimeConfig.DB_URL;
```

Answer (score 2):

1. Ensure that your .env file is located at the root of your project and not within the .src/ directory.
2. Utilize NEXT_PUBLIC_"name of your variable" for setting up your environment variable.
3. Restart the server.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, Im pasting REACT_APP_API_URL instead of NEXT_PUBLIC_API_URL.

Answer (score 1):

from document
https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/building-your-application/configuring/environment-variables

use NEXT_PUBLIC_[...] exp: NEXT_PUBLIC_API_URL

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

1. Check Your .Env Files:

   Make sure you've got defined your surroundings variables in an
   appropriate .Env documents. In Next.Js, you may use one-of-a-kind
   .Env files for exceptional environments (e.G., .Env.Local for
   neighborhood development and .Env.Production for manufacturing).
   Ensure that the variables you're looking to get entry to are defined
   in the correct .Env file.
2. Restart Your Development Server:

   After adding or enhancing environment variables, ensure to restart
   your development server. Sometimes, modifications to surroundings
   variables won't take effect until the server is restarted.
3. Use process.env to Access Environment Variables:

   In Next.js, you can access environment variables use of process.env. For
   example:

```js
const myVar = process.env.MY_VARIABLE;
```

Answer (score 0):

`process.env` only works in server not in browser so it will show undefined. To fix it, use `NEXT_PUBLIC_` before APi key in `.env.local` or `.env`. This solution works.

Answer (score 0):

This is very simple, I don't know why people are making this so complex, Just follow the below said steps.

1. Please keep your `.env.local` file inside the project root directory `myproject/.env.local`
2. Environment variable sample under `.env.local` is following -

   `NEXT_PUBLIC_MY_PACIFIC=Asia`
3. Please restart your server, by stopping the server and again starting it (`mandatory`).
4. Use Environment variable as following -

   `process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_MY_PACIFIC`

This is what you all have to do, I've done in version `NextJS` 14.0 , Hope it would help many one.