# Next.js 12 ( with react ): Cannot read env variables, process.env is undefined

Tags: reactjs, next.js, environment-variables

I'm using next.js 12 with a react app.

I have the following .env.local file:

`NEXT_PUBLIC_DEVELOPMENT_ENV_VARIABLE="public_development_variable"`

I start the dev server and in the browser i do:
`console.log('###ENV', process.env)`
and i always get undefined.

In the logs i have this that confirms that the env file was readed:
`info  - Loaded env from /Users/testdash/.env.local`

But process.env is always empty

Comment: Does this answer your question? [next.js environment variables are undefined (Next.js 10.0.5)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66137368/next-js-environment-variables-are-undefined-next-js-10-0-5)

Comment: Hi, nope. Already tried

Comment: You have to reference the environment variable by its full name. Try logging `console.log(process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_DEVELOPMENT_ENV_VARIABLE)`.

Answer (score 5):

If you need to share your environment variables with the browser, prefix them with  `NEXT_PUBLIC_` and it will be accessible at runtime. All other environment variables are replaced with their values.

e.g.
`NEXT_PUBLIC_ALGOLIA_INDEX`

Answer (score 2):

The docs mention it here: https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next.config.js/environment-variables

> Next.js will replace process.env.customKey with 'my-value' at build time. Trying to destructure process.env variables won't work due to the nature of webpack DefinePlugin.

Comment: Edited my answer, the method of setting the env variables wasn't important, it's the fact that the variables themselves get replaced with their values at build time.

Answer (score 0):

I just use .env instead of .env.local and it works great locally on Digitalocean or Azure (using nextjs 12)