# GraphQL Fetch Working in Page Component Only

Tags: javascript, reactjs, graphql, next.js

I'm using `fetch()` to query GraphQL in `lib/api.js` like so:

```
const API_URL = process.env.WORDPRESS_API_URL

async function fetchAPI(query, { variables } = {}) {
  const headers = { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' }

  const res = await fetch(API_URL, {
    method: 'POST',
    headers,
    body: JSON.stringify({
      query,
      variables,
    }),
  })

  const json = await res.json()
  if (json.errors) {
    console.error(json.errors)
    throw new Error('Failed to fetch API')
  }
  return json.data
}
```

...

```
export async function getPostsByCategory(slug, batchSize, endCursor) {
  const data = await fetchAPI(
    `
    query ($slug: String!, $batchSize: Int, $endCursor: String) {
      posts(first: $batchSize, after: $endCursor, where: {categoryName: $slug}) {
        pageInfo {
          hasNextPage
          endCursor
        }
        edges {
          node {
            id
            categories {
              edges {
                node {
                  name
                  slug
                  id
                }
              }
            }
            date
            featuredImage {
              node {
                sourceUrl(size: MEDIUM)
                altText
              }
            }
            slug
            title
          }
        }
      }
    }
  `,
    {
      variables: { slug, batchSize, endCursor },
    }
  )
  return data
}
```

If I call `getPostsByCategory()` in my page component [slug].js inside of `getStaticProps()` it returns data as expected. If, however, I use the same function `getStaticProps()` outside of get static props like so...

```
async function getPostsByCategory() {
    const moreArticles = await getMorePostsByCategory(categorySlug, 24, posts.pageInfo.endCursor)
    setFilteredArticles(...posts.edges, ...moreArticles.edges)
}

...

<div onClick={loadMoreArticles}>
    Load More
</div>
```

I get the `unexpected token in json at position 0 graphql` error.

If, instead, I move the entire fetch logic into the page component like so...

```
async function getPostsByCategory() {
    const headers = { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' }
    const query = 
        `query ($slug: String!, $batchSize: Int, $endCursor: String) {
            morePosts: posts(first: $batchSize, after: $endCursor, where: {categoryName: $slug}) {
              pageInfo {
                hasNextPage
                endCursor
              }
              edges {
                cursor
                node {
                  id
                  categories {
                    edges {
                      node {
                        name
                        slug
                        id
                      }
                    }
                  }
                  date
                  featuredImage {
                    node {
                      sourceUrl(size: MEDIUM)
                      altText
                    }
                  }
                  slug
                  title
                }
              }
            }
          }
        `
    const variables = {slug:categorySlug, batchSize:24, endCursor: endCursor || posts?.pageInfo.endCursor}
    const res = await fetch('http://localhost:10083/graphql', {
        method: 'POST',
        headers,
        body: JSON.stringify({
            query,
            variables
        }
            ),
    })
    const json = await res.json()
    if (json.errors) {
        console.error(json.errors)
        throw new Error('Failed to fetch API')
    }
    
    return json?.data
}
```

... we return the expected data. I'm wondering if there's some limitation to fetching data in page components I don't know of. Any information about this is appreciated.

Comment: What does the `getMorePostsByCategory` function look like? Or is that `getPostsByCategory`?

Comment: It's identical to getPostsByCategory(), and I planned to refactor them into one function eventually, but wanted to get it working first. Here's the thing, though. I've isolated the issue and it has to do with `process.env.WORDPRESS_API_URL` being undefined in my client side function. I'm at this very moment trying to figure out why.

Comment: If I change `const res = await fetch('http://localhost:10083/graphql', {...` to `const res = await fetch(process.env.WORDPRESS_API_URL, {...` I get the "unexpected token in json at position 0 graphql" error again. And that's because the url is undefined.

Comment: Found the issue. Described here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66137368/next-js-environment-variables-are-undefined-next-js-10-0-5

Comment: Yeah, you need to prefix the env var with `NEXT_PUBLIC_` to expose it to the browser.

Comment: I was so close to discovering this before I posted this question. I fully intended to test without the variable but I lost the mental thread I guess.