While using UseState the env variables are not accessible, is there an alternative of accessing those environment variables?
I am developing project using Sanity and Next.js, where I have a grid of products, and in this grid, while the product Cards are correctly mapped and displayed there is a button. while clicking on that button it shows a description of the product with various pictures of the product.
On the first hand the problem was that the images within the useState toogle doesn't show up. I understand this, because in react once You use the useState the state of the DOM evolves (which is the expected behaviour) but the environment variables within the new state is not the same as the primary runtime. So on the  toggle the images doesn't show up.
Here is how I import the sanity client:
// sanity.js this file is located within a component that is imported in the pages 
import { createClient } from '@sanity/client'
import imageUrlBuilder from '@sanity/image-url';


const client = createClient({
  projectId: process.env.SANITY_PROJECT_ID, 
  dataset: process.env.SANITY_DATASET,
  useCdn: true, 
  apiVersion: '2024-09-20'
});

const builder = imageUrlBuilder(client);

export function urlFor(source) {
  return builder.image(source);
}

export default client;

this client is correctly imported at the upstream of the project, but here comes the issue;
"use client";

import React, { useState } from 'react';
import Link from 'next/link';
import Image from 'next/image';
import { urlFor } from '../../sanity.js';

const ProductCard = ({ product }) => {
  const [showPopup, setShowPopup] = useState(false);

  const togglePopup = () => {
    setShowPopup(!showPopup);
  };

  return (
    <div className="bg-white rounded-lg shadow-md p-4 m-4">

here the image shows using the old env variables
 <Image
        src={urlFor(product.images[0]).url()}
        alt={product.title}
        width={100}
        height={50}
        className="w-full h-48 object-cover rounded-t-lg" />
      <h2 className="text-xl font-semibold mt-4">{product.title}</h2>
      <button
        onClick={togglePopup}
        className="mt-4 bg-lime-700 text-white py-2 px-4 rounded-full hover:bg-lime-800"
      >
    

Voir en detail
      </button>

      {showPopup && (
        <div className="fixed inset-0 bg-gray-800 bg-opacity-75 flex items-center 
          justify-center z-50 w-full">
          <div className="bg-white rounded-lg p-8 container">
            <button
              onClick={togglePopup}
              className="absolute top-3 right-3 bg-slate-500 text-white py-1 px-2 
           rounded-full hover:bg-slate-900"
            >
              X
            </button>
            <div className="grid grid-cols-1 sm:grid-cols-2 md:grid-cols-3 lg:grid- 
              cols-4 gap-4">

but here it no more shows normaly because the link used for accessing the sanity.cdn requires the appropriate projectId and project dataset which are stored within the .env file which are no more accessible here because the DOM has evolved.
{product.images.map((image) => (
                <Image
                  key={image._key}
                  src={urlFor(image.asset).url()}
                  alt={product.title}
                  width={100}
                  height={50}
                  className='w-full h-48 object-cover rounded-t-lg'
                />

              ))}

            </div>


            <h2 className="text-xl font-semibold mt-4">{product.title}</h2>
            <p className="mt-4">{product.description}</p>
            <p className="mt-4 text-lg font-semibold">Pour plus d'informations</p><br> 
           </br>

            <Link className="btn btn-primary z-0 py-[14px]" href="/contact" rel="">
              Contactez-nous
            </Link>
          </div>
        </div>
      )}
    </div>
  );
};

export default ProductCard;

The solution I actually found was to put the ProjectId and the dataset directly within the code, so it works, but I know it is completely unsafe & unsecure to proceed this way. So, is there a safe and secure way to make the env available even when the dom evolves/ the useState activated?

The problem is in your naming of the environment variables. For you to be able to access them in client components, you need to name them NEXT_PUBLIC_VARIABLE_NAME and use them like process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_VARIABLE_NAME. So for example, SANITY_PROJECT_ID should become NEXT_PUBLIC_SANITY_PROJECT_ID and process.env.SANITY_PROJECT_ID should become process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_SANITY_PROJECT_ID. It's in the docs.

Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66137368/next-js-environment-variables-are-undefined-next-js-10-0-5

This question is similar to: next.js environment variables are undefined (Next.js 10.0.5). If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

yes, Thank you guys. I've read the similar problems, but the main difference is that mine is calling the environment variable within a use state. Note: when calling the same env var in other parts of the app, it works perfectly fine.

@SyedM.Sannan, your answer is true in certain circumstances. But according to the docs When you prefix an environment variable with NEXT_PUBLIC_, it makes that variable accessible on both the client-side and the server-side. This means the variable will be included in the JavaScript bundle sent to the browser. but the var I try to pass are sensitive.. and once it can be seen on the browser it's the same as putting it in the code as I did.

@Aro If your variables are sensitive, then you shouldn't use "use client", and if you want to use useState, then you must use "use client". Case in point being that having both in the same place is inherently contradictory and you should architect your code in a different manner. How you should do that is off-topic for this question, but a brief way would be to have the code that accesses the environment variable on the server side, and fetch whatever value you need to on the client side and then store it inside the state.

@SyedM.Sannan, Yes true.
